# parallel sections with openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, sections

Hi,

I am trying to run this code in parrallel sections with openmp

I wanted to speed up its execution. These blocs can by calculated independently at every time step *t*.

Unfortunatly, instead, the code is slowed down by openmp. I have been looking for concurrency but did not see any problem.

Did I use the sections argument correctly?

Is there a better parallalisation framework that I should use?

All the best

```
#define Nx 300
#define Ny 100
int main()
{
int i, j, t=0, it=0;


double vort[Nx][Ny], psi[Nx][Ny], ux[Nx][Ny], uy[Nx][Ny];

double fpsi[Nx][Ny];
double a[Nx][Ny], b[Nx][Ny],c[Nx][Ny], d[Nx][Ny], e[Nx][Ny], ee[Nx][Ny];


//tridiagonal coefficient
//coefficient for the internal grid for vort. Indexed from 0 to Nx-3 or Ny-3 to calculate the interior grid point only. The idix are shiffted of (+1,+1) compare to vort or psi or ux or uy.
//double DDx[Nx-2], AAx[Nx-2], BBx[Nx-2], CCx[Nx-2],    DDy[Ny-2], AAy[Ny-2],BBy[Ny-2], CCy[Ny-2];
double DDx[Nx], AAx[Nx], BBx[Nx], CCx[Nx],    DDy[Ny], AAy[Ny],BBy[Ny], CCy[Ny];
double epsx[Nx][Ny], epsy[Nx][Ny]; //same dimension than ux and uy
//double vortx[Nx-2], vorty[Ny-2];
double vortx[Nx], vorty[Ny];
double cx[Nx][Ny], cy[Nx][Ny]; //same dimension than ux and uy


//coefficient for the ADI
double n[Nx][Ny];
double DDnx[Nx], AAnx[Nx], BBnx[Nx], CCnx[Nx],    DDny[Ny], AAny[Ny],BBny[Ny], CCny[Ny];
double nx[Nx], ny[Ny];

//coefficient for the ADI
double cO2[Nx][Ny];
double DDcx[Nx], AAcx[Nx], BBcx[Nx], CCcx[Nx],    DDcy[Ny], AAcy[Ny],BBcy[Ny], CCcy[Ny];
double cO2x[Nx], cO2y[Ny];

//coefficient for the ADI
double cls[Nx][Ny];
double DDclsx[Nx], AAclsx[Nx], BBclsx[Nx], CCclsx[Nx],    DDclsy[Ny], AAclsy[Ny],BBclsy[Ny], CCclsy[Ny];
double clsx[Nx], clsy[Ny];

//coefficient for the ADI
double pvd[Nx][Ny];
double DDpvdx[Nx], AApvdx[Nx], BBpvdx[Nx], CCpvdx[Nx],    DDpvdy[Ny], AApvdy[Ny],BBpvdy[Ny], CCpvdy[Ny];
double pvdx[Nx], pvdy[Ny];
```

////gap in the code display...///

```
for (t=tIni; t<tmax; t++)
    //      for (t=1; t<4; t++)
{

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //calcul coef upwind differentiation
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
    {

        for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
        {
            cx[i][j]=ux[i][j]*DtDx;
            cy[i][j]=uy[i][j]*DtDx;

            if(ux[i][j]>=0)
            {
                epsx[i][j]=1;
            }
            else
            {
                epsx[i][j]=-1;
            }

            if(uy[i][j]>=0)
            {
                epsy[i][j]=1;
            }
            else
            {
                epsy[i][j]=-1;
            }

        }

    }

#pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la concentration de bacterie
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            ADI_N(n, cO2, AAnx, BBnx, CCnx, DDnx, AAny, BBny, CCny, DDny, cx, cy, epsx, epsy, nx, ny, DtDbDxs, Dxs2);
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la concentration d'oxygene
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            ADI_C(cO2, n, AAcx, BBcx, CCcx, DDcx, AAcy, BBcy, CCcy, DDcy, cx, cy, epsx, epsy, cO2x, cO2y, DtDO2Dxs, Dxs2, gamma);
        }
        /*for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
         {
         cO2[i][Ny-1]=1.;
         }*/

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la concentration de cellulose
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            ADI_Cls(cls, n, cO2tmp, AAclsx, BBclsx, CCclsx, DDclsx, AAclsy, BBclsy, CCclsy, DDclsy, cx, cy, epsx, epsy, clsx, clsy, DtDclsDxs, Dxs2, Dt*kpvd, seuilCls, seuilStopCls);

        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la concentration de poyverdine
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            ADI_Pvd(pvd, n, cO2, AApvdx, BBpvdx, CCpvdx, DDpvdx, AApvdy, BBpvdy, CCpvdy, DDpvdy, cx, cy, epsx, epsy, pvdx, pvdy, DtDpvdDxs, Dxs2, Dt*kpvd, seuilCls, seuilStopCls);
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la vorticité
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {

            ADI(vort, psi, n, cls, AAx, BBx, CCx, DDx, AAy, BBy, CCy, DDy, cx, cy, epsx, epsy, vortx, vorty, DtDxsRe, Dxs, coefMass, coefMassCls);
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la stream function
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            // Preparation de la force qui agit sur la stream function (potentiel vecteur)
            for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
            {
                for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
                {


                    fpsi[i][j]= - vort[i][j]*Dxs; //multiplie par Dxs car les coefficient son multiplie par beta=Dxs/Dys. Donc Dxs est l'unite spatiale.

                    if(isnan(fpsi[i][j]))
                    {
                        cout<<"error psi nan "<<__FILE__<<" line "<<__LINE__<<endl;
                        exit(2);
                    }

                }
            }


            //SOR
            //sorPoissonChebyshev(psi, fpsi, a, b, c, d, e, ee, Nx-1, Ny-1, rjac, it, Nitmax, relax, tol);
            sorPoissonChebyshev(psi, fpsi, a, b, c, d, e, ee, Nx, Ny, rjac, it, relax, Nitmax, tol);

            //condition aux bords. Psi constant sur la frontiere. Mise a zero pour le SOR
            for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
            {
                psi[i][0]=0;
                psi[i][Ny-1]=0;
            }

            for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
            {
                psi[0][j]=0;
                psi[Nx-1][j]=0;
            }
        }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //calcul de la vitesse
           ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma omp section
        {
            for (i=1; i<Nx-1; i++)
            {
                for (j=1; j<Ny-1; j++)
                {
                    ux[i][j]=(psi[i][j+1]-psi[i][j-1])/Dx2;
                    uy[i][j]=-(psi[i+1][j]-psi[i-1][j])/Dx2;
                }
            }

            //Boudary conditions
            for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
            {
                ux[i][Ny-1]=ux[i][Ny-2]; //free slip
                //ux[i][Ny-1]=0; //no slip
                uy[i][Ny-1]=0;

                ux[i][0]=0;
                uy[i][0]=0;
            }
            for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
            {
                ux[Nx-1][j]=0;
                uy[Nx-1][j]=0;

                ux[0][j]=0;
                uy[0][j]=0;
            }
        }



    }

}
}
```

---EDIT : - Remove the tmp - ADI function

```
void ADI_N(double n[][Ny], double cO2[][Ny],
       double AAx[], double BBx[], double CCx[], double DDx[],
       double AAy[], double BBy[], double CCy[], double DDy[],
       double cx[][Ny], double cy[][Ny], double epsx[][Ny], double epsy[][Ny],
       double nx[], double ny[], double DbDtDxs, double Dxs2)

{

int i=0, j=0;

for (i=0; i<Nx; i++) //interior points
{
    for (j=0; j<Ny; j++) //interior points
    {
        if (cO2[i][j]>seuilO2) // Seuil en dessous du quel les bacteries ne pousse pas.
        {
            n[i][j]= n[i][j] * ( 1 + Dt /  tempsDeDivBact * cO2[i][j] ); // n et cO2 sont normalizée
        }

    }
}


////////////calcul sur y////////////
//calcul coef ADI


for (i=0; i<Nx; i++) //interior points
{
    for (j=1; j<Ny-1; j++) //interior points
    {

        //non conservative forme
        if (i==0)
        {
            AAy[j] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;

            BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs;

            CCy[j] = - .5 * DbDtDxs;

            DDy[j] = .5 * DbDtDxs * n[1][j]
            + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j]
            + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i+1][j];

        }
        else if (i==Nx-1)
        {
            AAy[j] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;

            BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs;

            CCy[j] = - .5 * DbDtDxs;

            DDy[j] = .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i-1][j]
            + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j]
            + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[Nx-2][j];

        }
        else //conservative forme
        {

             AAy[j] = -.5 * ( .5 * (1 + epsy[i][j]) * cy[i][j-1] + DbDtDxs);

             BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs + .5 * epsy[i][j] * cy[i][j];

             CCy[j] = .5 * ( .5 * ( 1 - epsy[i][j] ) * cy[i][j+1] - DbDtDxs);

             DDy[j] = .5 * (.5 * ( 1 + epsx[i][j] ) * cx[i-1][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i-1][j]
             + ( 1 - DbDtDxs - .5 * epsx[i][j] * cx[i][j] ) * n[i][j]
             + .5 * (- .5 * ( 1 - epsx[i][j] ) * cx[i+1][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i+1][j];

            /*AAy[j] = -.5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j-1] + DbDtDxs);

            BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;

            CCy[j] = .5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j+1] - DbDtDxs);

            DDy[j] = .5 * (.5 * cx[i-1][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i-1][j]
            + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j]
            + .5 * (- .5 * cx[i+1][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i+1][j];
            */
        }

        ny[j] = n[i][j];
    }


    //boundary condition values no flux n[i][j-1]=n[i][j+1] and substraction of a[0]*n[i][j] for tridaig calculation.
    //non conservative forme
    if (i==0) {
        j=0; //DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j] - -( .5 * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 ) * n[i][j-1];
        DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][1];//AAy
        AAy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;
        CCy[j] = .5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j+1] - DbDtDxs);

        j=Ny-1;
        DDy[j] = .5 * ( DbDtDxs + cx[i][j]/2) * n[1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + .5 * ( DbDtDxs - cx[i][j]/2) * n[i+1][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][Ny-2]; //CCy
        AAy[j] = -.5 * ( .5  * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs);
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy
    }
    else if(i==Nx-1)
    { j=0; //DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j] - -( .5 * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 ) * n[i][j-1];
        DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[Nx-2][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][1];
        AAy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;
        CCy[j] = .5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j+1] - DbDtDxs);

        j=Ny-1;
        DDy[j] = .5 * ( DbDtDxs + cx[i][j]/2) * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + .5 * ( DbDtDxs - cx[i][j]/2) * n[Nx-2][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][Ny-2];
        AAy[j] = -.5 * ( .5  * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs);
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy
    }
    else
    {
        j=0; //DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j] - -( .5 * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 ) * n[i][j-1];
        DDy[j] = DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][1];
        AAy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;
        CCy[j] = .5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j+1] - DbDtDxs);

        j=Ny-1;
        DDy[j] = .5 * ( DbDtDxs + cx[i][j]/2) * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + .5 * ( DbDtDxs - cx[i][j]/2) * n[i+1][j]
        + DbDtDxs/2 * n[i][Ny-2];
        AAy[j] = -.5 * ( .5  * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs);
        BBy[j] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCy[j] = 0; // pas utilise soustrait à DDy

    }



    tridiag_full(AAy, BBy, CCy, DDy, ny, Ny-1); //calcul les point en 0 et en Ny-1 inclus


    for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
    {
        n[i][j]=ny[j];
    }

}

////////////calcul sur x //////////
//calcul coef ADI
for (j=0; j<Ny; j++)
{


    for (i=1; i<Nx-1; i++)

    {


        //non conservative forme
        if(j==0)
        {

            AAx[i] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;
            BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
            CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

            DDx[i]= .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][1]
            + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j]
            + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][j+1];
        }

        else if(j==Ny-1)
        {

            AAx[i] = -.5* ( .5 * cx[i][j] + DbDtDxs );
            BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
            CCx[i] = .5 * ( .5 * cx[i][j] - DbDtDxs) ;

            DDx[i]= .5 * ( .5 * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j-1]
            + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j]
            + .5 * ( - .5 * cy[i][j] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i][Ny-2];
        }
        else //conservative forme
        {

             AAx[i] = -.5* ( .5 * ( 1 + epsx[i][j] ) * cx[i-1][j] + DbDtDxs );
             BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs + .5 * epsx[i][j] * cx[i][j];
             CCx[i] = .5 * ( .5 * ( 1 - epsx[i][j] ) * cx[i+1][j] - DbDtDxs) ;

             DDx[i]= .5 * ( .5 * ( 1 + epsy[i][j] ) * cy[i][j-1] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j-1]
             + ( 1 - DbDtDxs - .5 * epsy[i][j] * cy[i][j] ) * n[i][j]
             + .5 * (-.5 * ( 1 - epsy[i][j] ) * cy[i][j+1] + DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j+1];


        }


        nx[i]=n[i][j];

    }

    if(j==0)
    {
        i=0;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][j+1]
        -AAx[i];

        i=Nx-1;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][j+1]
        -CCx[i];

    }
    else if(j==Ny-1)
    {
        i=0;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * ( .5 * cx[i][j] + DbDtDxs);
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = .5 * (.5 * cx[i][j] - DbDtDxs );

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][j-1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][Ny-2]
        -AAx[i];

        i=Nx-1;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * ( .5 * cx[i][j] + DbDtDxs);
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = .5 * (.5 * cx[i][j] - DbDtDxs );

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][j-1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][Ny-2]
        -CCx[i];

    }
    else
    {
        i=0;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][j-1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][j+1]
        -AAx[i];

        i=Nx-1;
        AAx[i] = -.5 * DbDtDxs;
        BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs;
        CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

        DDx[i]= .5 *  DbDtDxs * n[i][j-1] + ( 1 - DbDtDxs ) * n[i][j] + .5 * DbDtDxs * n[i][j+1]
        -CCx[i];

    }


    //boundary condition values no flux n[i-1][j]=n[i+1][j] and substraction of a[0]*n[i][j] for tridaig calculation.
    i=0;
    DDx[i] = (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j] + 3*DbDtDxs/2 * n[i+1][j];
    AAx[i] = 0 ; //pas utlise soustrait à DDx
    BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;
    CCx[i] = - .5 * DbDtDxs ;

    i=Nx-1;
    DDx[i] = 3*DbDtDxs/2 * n[i-1][j] + (1-DbDtDxs) * n[i][j];
    AAx[i] = - .5* DbDtDxs;
    BBx[i] = 1 + DbDtDxs ;
    CCx[i] = 0 ; //pas utlise soustrait à DDx


    tridiag_full(AAx, BBx, CCx, DDx, nx, Nx-1); //calcul les point en 0 et en Nx-1 inclus

    for (i=0; i<Nx; i++)
    {
        n[i][j]=nx[i];

    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The index variables `i` & `j` are common across some of your sections which will cause synchronization issues between the sections and mostly incorrect output. Change it to either making the variables private for each section `#pragma omp section private(i,j)` or initialize them in each loop `for (int i=1; i<Nx-1; i++)`. I always prefer to initialize the variables in my loops, there by I don't accidentally reuse a stale value from previous iteration.

Comment: Hey, Of course this private(i,j) is essential thank you to point it out. Actually the slowdown is coming from elsewhere. All the vort, psi, etc, are 2D arrays double. To avoid the shared concurrency between pragma section I have made a tmp version of them (vorttmp,...). But with this new tmp 2Darray of size 300x150 I overload the memory of the computer and got a bad_exec... So I have found that in declaring all the array in static double vort[Nx][Ny] I did not had this last problem. But It slows down the code 10x! So I have remove the static and the tmp var now but get some shared concurrency.

Comment: I don't know the implementation of the `ADI*` methods, but if they are all just reading these arrays and not modifying them, then you don't need to create copies of these arrays. Multiple threads reading from common location will not cause concurrency issue, the concurrency issue only comes into picture when multiple threads are writing to a location. So I would suggest that you don't create the copies. Your last `omp parallel for` is outside the `omp parallel sections` block so that will maintain consistency when you write back to your original arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. Actually every ADI fonction write one of these 2D array. ADI write vort, ADI_N write n, ADI_C write cO2... Is it keen on making concurrency?

Comment: If `ADI` is only modifying `vort`, `ADI_N` only `n` and so on, then you don't need to synchronize or make any of the other arrays as private or create copies, because looks like your code does not perform any concurrent writes within the parallel sections. Can you also modify the original code in the question to highlight where you are creating the temporary arrays etc...

Comment: Well then I have removed the vorttmp,etc. What I dont get is that by doing that the code with pragma takes 5450s and without 235s!

Comment: One guess is that as the array sizes are big (the double dimension arrays are ~230KB each), running all the sections in parallel is causing lot of cache misses and hence the performance degradation. Try removing the `omp parallel sections` and each section, and instead put `omp parallel for` inside each `ADI_*` method. This should avoid any cache misses and should give better performance than your single threaded execution.

Comment: Ok I got it, it memory cache effect. I tried what you proposed, but it has not much effect and I found why. The code is spending most of its time in the tridiag solver. So parallelizing the calculation of the ADI coeff has not much effect. I am now looking for a way to speed up the triadiag solver. (I am already using this fast thomas algo so I am gonna hunt toward the BLAS/LAPACK librairy)